# MySQL Opposite of SELECT MAX

Tags: mysql, max

I'm trying to find all rows in a database that are NOT MAX(bid_ts).  Can I use !MAX(bid_ts) or is there a better way to do this?

```
$auctionswinning = "
  SELECT 
    listings.end_date, 
    listings.user_id, 
    listings.title, 
    listings.auc_fp, 
    listings.id, 
    listings.auc_image1 
  FROM listings 
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
     listing_id, 
     user_id, 
     !MAX(bid_ts) maxDate
    FROM bids
    GROUP BY listing_id, user_id
  ) bids ON listings.id = bids.listing_id
  WHERE 
   bids.user_id=$userid
   AND listings.end_date > NOW()";
```

Comment: What are the table columns you are working with?

Comment: Please let us know the context of you usage of MAX, such as your WHERE clause.

Comment: And are you doing this with aggregate groups, or the single `MAX(bid_ts)` value for the whole table?

Comment: I've edited my question to include the entire query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    listings.end_date, 
    listings.user_id, 
    listings.title, 
    listings.auc_fp, 
    listings.id, 
    listings.auc_image1 
FROM listings 
INNER JOIN (SELECT
                 listing_id, 
                 user_id, 
                 bid_ts maxDate
            FROM bids
            WHERE bid_ts NOT IN (SELECT MAX(bid_ts) FROM bids)
            GROUP BY listing_id, user_id
            ) bids ON listings.id = bids.listing_id
WHERE bids.user_id=$userid
AND listings.end_date > NOW()
```

Comment: That gives me the error... sql error: every derived table must have it's own alias

Comment: YOU ARE AWESOME!  Thank you! It works perfectly.  Who knows how many hours I've spent on this...  I'm going to study this for a little while so I understand it better.

Comment: learn joins, where, group by and variables deeply they will give you a lot of benefits on queies

Comment: How could I change this query to give me the one row with the maxdate?

Comment: can you post the structure and desired result so that i can understand

Comment: Can I move this to chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21874/discussion-between-budove-and-raheel-shan)

Comment: @Budove you can chat now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a subquery for this :

```
SELECT bid_ts FROM tbl WHERE bid_ts <> (SELECT MAX(bid_ts) FROM tbl);
```

Comment: have you tried running that...?

Comment: I did but didn't have any luck with it.  This is way more complicated than I'm used to messing with.  I haven't had the need to nest queries before.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT bid_ts
FROM tbl
HAVING bid_ts <> MAX(bid_ts)
```

I haven't tried it, and it's best to avoid HAVING, but it should get you started.

Comment: This makes no sense and doesn't work.